# 404 - Page not found error while using Google's Instant Preview in Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, 404, error-code

While I was comparing my website's live page with Google's Instant Preview of a page in Google Webmaster Tools, I got a `404 - Page not found` error.

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Did you try accessing your page from any other server (such as a proxy)? Is your server blocking access to only Google servers?

Comment: Check to make sure the page is not blocked in your _robots.txt_, or by other means to block robots.

Comment: 404 in the browser when accessing the tool, or the tool showed a 404 from your website?